# About springboot, need to write a set of user login code, and spring security, JWT configuration. Is there a ready-made third-party solution?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

About springboot, need to write a set of user login code, and spring security, JWT configuration. It's very troublesome. Can we not write it myself,Is there a ready-made third-party solution?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, there are existing frameworks and ready-to-use built applications. Keep in mind, you will always need to make some twists to suit your needs, so you will most certainly need to understand them anyway.

If you are building a standalone Springboot application, I recommend you to look at Spring security or Apache Shiro. I followed this article to secure the Springboot application at my work.

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/

---

There are many reasons for choosing this repo. My client needs a single Springboot application (not a stack of Springcloud micro-services), where the security framework must be well integrated with the application. Moreover, this repo includes both password and OAuth2 social login implementations, and good redirection strategies (based on cookie). It is obvious that the programmer behind this repo knows Spring Security and the code is ready to use.